# WebLogic EJB 8.1 unhandled exception?

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic8.x

I am seeing the following error in logs from last week:

```
<Feb 7> <Warning> <WLW> <000000> <Id=top-level; Method=processes.FTPInboundProcess.subscription(); Failure=com.bea.wli.bpm.runtime.UnhandledProcessException: Unhandled process exception [ServiceException]> 
<Feb 7> <Info> <EJB> <BEA-010213> <Message-Driven EJB: AsyncDispatcher's transaction was rolledback. The transaction details are: Xid=BEA1-3C63D2E9CC47D571774C(183265728),Status=Rolled back.
```

The code is below:

FTPInboundProcess.jpd

```
package processes;

import com.bea.data.RawData;
import com.bea.jpd.JpdContext;
import com.bea.jpd.JpdContext.ExceptionInfo;
import com.bea.jpd.ProcessDefinition;
import com.bea.wli.eventGenerator.FileEventGeneratorDocument;
import com.bea.wli.eventGenerator.TimerEventGeneratorDocument;
import com.bea.xml.XmlObject;
import com.bea.xml.XmlTokenSource;
import com.integration.exception.AppException;
import com.integration.util.EnvProperties;
import com.integration.util.KeyGenerator;
import com.integration.util.LogParameters;
import com.integration.util.MessageDataOperation;
import com.integration.util.PASLevel;
import com.integration.util.PASLogger;
import com.integration.util.StringEncrypter;
import com.integration.util.Utility;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import ftp.InterfaceDocument.Interface;
import ftp.InterfacesDocument;
import ftp.InterfacesDocument.Factory;
import ftp.InterfacesDocument.Interfaces;
import inbound.IFileAdapter;
import inbound.impl.FTPClientImpl;
import inbound.impl.FileClientImpl;
import inbound.impl.SFTPClientImpl;
import outbound.PostProcess;

public class FTPInboundProcess
  implements ProcessDefinition
{
  public boolean bIsFtpDeleteSuccess;
  public boolean isWriteToLocalDirSuccess;
  public String fileArchiveDir;
  public boolean isChDirSuccess;
  public byte[] ftpData;
  public boolean isPutSuccess;
  public TimerEventGeneratorDocument timerEventGeneratorDoc;
  public FileEventGeneratorDocument fileEventGeneratorDoc;
  public RawData inputRawData;
  public IFileAdapter ftp;
  public static String PROCESS_NAME = "FileXFRI";
  public String processLabel;
  public long processStartTime;
  public long originalStartTime;
  public long processId;
  public long parentProcessId;
  public String key;
  public String protocol;
  public String documentKey;
  public boolean bAppException;
  public boolean bMesageInorder;
  public boolean bNewMessage;
  public String errorStr;
  public String sftpkey;
  public String fileName;
  public int fileCounter;
  public String emailUser;
  public transient Logger logger;
  static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public FTPInboundProcess.Callback callback;
  public String ftpHostName;
  public int ftpPort;
  public String ftpUserName;
  public String ftpPassword;
  public String ftpDir;
  public String ftpArchDir;
  public String ftpLocalDir;
  public String filePattern;
  public String isFtpPostActionDeleteRequired;
  public String isFtpPostActionArchiveRequired;
  public String isEncryptRequired;
  public long fileSize;
  public String interfaceId;
  public String emailYN;
  public HashMap dataMap;
  public XmlObject inputXML;
  public String[] listOfFTPFiles;
  public boolean isFTPConnected;
  JpdContext context;
  int postProcessReturnvalue;

  public void subscription(XmlObject x0, TimerEventGeneratorDocument x1)
  {
    this.inputXML = x0;
    this.timerEventGeneratorDoc = x1;
  }

  void initProcessVariables()
  {
    this.processStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.processLabel = "";
    this.processId = 0L;
    this.postProcessReturnvalue = 0;

    this.parentProcessId = 0L;
    this.documentKey = "";
    this.bAppException = false;
    this.errorStr = "";

    this.fileSize = 0L;
    this.interfaceId = "";

    this.emailYN = "";
    this.emailUser = "";

    this.dataMap = new HashMap();
  }

  public void init()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      this.logger = PASLogger.getLogger("PAS." + PROCESS_NAME);

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINER, "Timer InputXML :" + this.inputXML.xmlText());

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINER, "Type::" + this.inputXML.getClass());

      initProcessVariables();

      String xmlText = this.inputXML.xmlText();

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINER, "INPUT::" + xmlText);

      InterfacesDocument input = InterfacesDocument.Factory.parse(xmlText);



      this.interfaceId = input.getInterfaces().getInterfaceArray()[0].getId();



      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINER, "Interface id : " + ((InterfacesDocument)this.inputXML).getInterfaces().getInterfaceArray(0).getId());

      this.processId = KeyGenerator.generateKey("PROCESS_ID");

      this.documentKey = (PROCESS_NAME + "::FTP::" + this.interfaceId + "::" + this.processId);

      this.key = (PROCESS_NAME + "::FTP::" + this.interfaceId + "::" + this.processId);



      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINER, "Parsing Input Document End:" + System.currentTimeMillis());


      this.processLabel = ("Key=" + this.key + ",ProcessId=" + this.processId + ",InterfaceId=" + this.interfaceId);



      this.processStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


      MessageDataOperation.insertMessageData(this.processId, this.documentKey, PROCESS_NAME, this.key, this.processStartTime, this.parentProcessId);


      updateProcessLabel(this.processLabel);

      this.protocol = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".PROTOCOL");

      this.ftpHostName = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FTPHOST");
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINEST, " ftpHostName :" + this.ftpHostName);
      try
      {
        this.ftpPort = Integer.parseInt(EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".PORT"));
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        this.logger.log(PASLevel.WARNING, "FTP Port not defined for the Interface :" + this.interfaceId + " .... using default port");
        this.ftpPort = 21;
      }
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " ftpPort :" + this.ftpPort);

      this.sftpkey = Utility.nullToStr(EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".SFTPKEY"));
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " SFTPKEY :" + this.sftpkey);

      this.dataMap.put("SFTPKEY", this.sftpkey);

      this.ftpUserName = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FTPUSER");
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " ftpUserName :" + this.ftpUserName);

      this.ftpPassword = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FTPPASSWORD");
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " ftpPassword :" + this.ftpPassword);

      this.filePattern = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FILEPATTERN");
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " filePattern :" + this.filePattern);

      this.ftpArchDir = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FTPARCH");
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " ftpArchDir :" + this.ftpArchDir);

      this.ftpDir = Utility.nullToStr(EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FTPDIR"));

      this.ftpLocalDir = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FTPLOCALDIR");

      this.fileArchiveDir = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FILEARCHIVEDIR");

      this.isFtpPostActionDeleteRequired = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FTPPOSTDELETE");
      this.isEncryptRequired = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".ENCRYPT");

      this.isFtpPostActionArchiveRequired = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".FTPPOSTARCHIVE");

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " ftpLocalDir :" + this.ftpLocalDir);
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " isFtpPostActionArchiveRequired :" + this.isFtpPostActionArchiveRequired);
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, " isFtpPostActionDeleteRequired :" + this.isFtpPostActionDeleteRequired);

      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  void updateProcessLabel(String label)
  {
    this.context.setProcessLabel(this.processLabel);
  }

  public boolean isAppException()
  {
    return this.bAppException;
  }

  public boolean isMessageInorder()
  {
    return this.bMesageInorder;
  }

  String getErrorEmailUser(Object[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      if ((args == null) || (args.length == 0)) {
        return "";
      }
      this.emailUser = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".EMAIL_USER");

      return this.emailUser;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, "ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));
    }
    return "";
  }

  public void context_onInitialMessageFailure(String methodName, Object[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      this.processId = Utility.context_onInitialMessageFailure(PROCESS_NAME, args, this.logger);

      String body = "Due to the error the interface file could not be sent. \n";

      body = body + "System will retry the file after sometime.";

      this.errorStr = "";

      sendErrorEmail(body, getErrorEmailUser(args));

      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, "ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void globalExceptionHandler()
    throws Exception
  {
    Exception e = null;
    try
    {
      e = this.context.getExceptionInfo().getException();
      this.errorStr = e.getMessage();
    }
    catch (Throwable localThrowable) {}
    this.bAppException = Utility.globalExceptionHandler(e, this.logger, PROCESS_NAME, this.processId, this.parentProcessId, "", this.inputRawData.byteValue(), "xml", true);
    if (this.bAppException) {
      this.processLabel = (this.processLabel + ",AppException , " + e.getClass());
    } else {
      this.processLabel = (this.processLabel + ",SystemException , " + e.getClass());
    }
    updateProcessLabel(this.processLabel);

    this.logger.log(PASLevel.INFO, "Exception Raised in Process ,  Process Label:" + this.processLabel);
  }

  public void systemExceptionProcessing()
    throws Exception
  {}

  public void sendDataErrorEmail()
    throws Exception
  {
    String body = "Due to the error the file could not sent \n\n\n";

    body = body + ",Filename=" + this.fileName;

    this.emailUser = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".EMAIL_USER");

    sendErrorEmail(body, this.emailUser);
  }

  public void sendErrorEmail(String body, String to)
    throws Exception
  {
    String subject = "";
    String cc = "";
    String bcc = "";


    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    try
    {
      body = body + this.errorStr;

      subject = "Due to the error the interface file could not be sent. " + this.key;
      if ((to == null) || (to.equals(""))) {
        to = Utility.getErrorEmail();
      }
      Utility.sendEmail(PROCESS_NAME, this.processId, "Business", body, subject, to, "", cc, bcc, "");




      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, "ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  public boolean isMessageInorder1()
  {
    return this.bMesageInorder;
  }

  public void handleAppException()
    throws Exception
  {}

  public void cleanup()
    throws Exception
  {
    this.inputRawData = null;
  }

  public void setFilesCount()
    throws Exception
  {
    this.fileCounter = 0;
  }

  public void decrementFileCount()
    throws Exception
  {
    this.fileCounter += 1;
  }

  public boolean checkFileCounterCondition()
  {
    return this.fileCounter < this.listOfFTPFiles.length;
  }

  public void raiseFTPConnectionException()
    throws Exception
  {
    Exception e = new Exception("Error: FTP Connection Failure");

    this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, ":ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error: FTP Connection Failure", new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


    throw e;
  }

  public boolean isFTPConnected()
  {
    return this.ftp.isConnected();
  }

  public boolean checkNoOfFilesReceived()
  {
    if ((this.listOfFTPFiles != null) && (this.listOfFTPFiles.length > 0)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void sendEmail()
    throws Exception
  {
    String subject = "";
    String to = "";
    String cc = "";
    String bcc = "";
    String body = "";


    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    try
    {
      this.emailYN = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".EMAIL_YN");
      if ((this.emailYN != null) && (!this.emailYN.equals("Y"))) {
        return;
      }
      this.emailUser = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".EMAIL_USER");

      body = "Interface has processed the following file succesfully. :Filename:" + this.fileName;

      to = this.emailUser;

      subject = "Interface has sent the following file succesfully. Key::" + this.key + ":Filename:" + this.fileName;
      if ((to == null) || (to.equals("")))
      {
        this.logger.log(PASLevel.WARNING, "ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + "Email Receipent not specified.", new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, null));


        to = Utility.getErrorEmail();
      }
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "SCPExtract ... Sending an Email");


      Utility.sendEmail(PROCESS_NAME, this.processId, "Business", body, subject, to, "", cc, bcc, "");





      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, "ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void createFTPClient()
    throws Exception
  {
    if (this.protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("SFTP"))
    {
      this.ftp = new SFTPClientImpl();return;
    }
    if (this.protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("FTP"))
    {
      this.ftp = new FTPClientImpl();return;
    }
    this.ftp = new FileClientImpl();
  }

  public void connect()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      if (((this.protocol.equals("FTP")) || (this.protocol.equals("SFTP"))) && ((this.ftpUserName == null) || (this.ftpPassword == null) || (this.ftpHostName == null)))
      {
        Exception e = new Exception("ftpUserName = null || this.ftpPassword = null || ftpHostName = null");
        this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));



        throw e;
      }
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "Connecting to the server .... :" + this.ftpHostName);

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "Host:" + this.ftpHostName + ":User:" + this.ftpUserName + ":Password:" + this.ftpPassword);

      this.ftp.connect(this.ftpHostName, this.ftpPort, this.ftpUserName, this.ftpPassword, this.dataMap);

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "Connected to the server:" + this.ftpHostName);
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, "ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void getRemoteFilesList()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "Retriving List of Files .... :FtpDir:" + this.ftpDir);

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "File Pattern  .... ::" + this.filePattern);
      if (!this.ftpLocalDir.equals("")) {
        this.ftp.setLocalDir(this.ftpLocalDir);
      }
      if (!this.ftpDir.equals("")) {
        this.ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(this.ftpDir);
      }
      ArrayList list = this.ftp.listFiles(this.filePattern);

      this.listOfFTPFiles = new String[list.size()];

      System.arraycopy(list.toArray(), 0, this.listOfFTPFiles, 0, list.size());
      for (int ind = 0; ind < this.listOfFTPFiles.length; ind++) {
        this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "List of Files:" + this.listOfFTPFiles[ind]);
      }
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, "ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void disconnect()
    throws Exception
  {
    this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "Zero input files ..... Disconnecting ...");

    this.ftp.disconnect();
  }

  public void getFile()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      this.fileName = this.listOfFTPFiles[this.fileCounter];
      if (this.fileName == null) {
        throw new Exception(" FTP fileName is null");
      }
      ByteArrayOutputStream getFileByteArrayOutputStream = this.ftp.getFile(this.fileName);

      this.ftpData = getFileByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "Got File Data ...");

      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, ":ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void backup()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      String archiveYN = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".LOCALARCHIVE");

      String asciiYN = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".ASCII_YN");
      if (archiveYN.equals("Y"))
      {
        byte[] fileArchData;
        if ((asciiYN.equals("Y")) && (this.isEncryptRequired.equals("Y")))
        {
          StringEncrypter encrypter = new StringEncrypter();
          fileArchData = encrypter.encrypt(new String(this.ftpData)).getBytes();
        }
        else
        {
          fileArchData = this.ftpData;
        }
        Utility.createFile(this.fileArchiveDir + "/" + this.interfaceId + "_" + this.processId + "_" + this.fileName, fileArchData);
      }
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "File Archieved ...::" + archiveYN + "::EncryptionYN::" + this.isEncryptRequired);

      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, ":ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));



      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void disconnect1()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      this.ftp.disconnect();
      return;
    }
    catch (Throwable localThrowable) {}
  }

  public void disconnect2()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      this.ftp.disconnect();
      return;
    }
    catch (Throwable localThrowable) {}
  }

  public void doPostProcess()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      String sapPostProcessClass = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".POSTPROCESS");

      sapPostProcessClass = "washpost.pas.outbound.impl." + sapPostProcessClass;



      Map fileMap = new HashMap();

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "PostProcess ::" + sapPostProcessClass);
      if (!sapPostProcessClass.equals(""))
      {
        Class c = Class.forName(sapPostProcessClass);
        PostProcess postProcess = (PostProcess)c.newInstance();

        String passByRefFlag = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".REFERENCE_YN");
        byte[] tempFtpData = this.ftpData;
        if ((passByRefFlag != null) && (passByRefFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")))
        {
          String localDir = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".LOCALDIR");
          String localFileName = localDir + System.getProperty("file.separator") + this.fileName;
          Utility.createFile(localFileName, this.ftpData);
          tempFtpData = new byte[0];
        }
        this.postProcessReturnvalue = postProcess.doUpload(tempFtpData, this.fileName, this.interfaceId, this.processId, fileMap);


        this.logger.log(PASLevel.FINE, "***** PostProcess Return::" + this.postProcessReturnvalue);


        return;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, ":ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));



      this.postProcessReturnvalue = -1;
      this.errorStr = e.getMessage();
      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void writeFileToExceptionDir()
    throws Exception
  {
    String exceptionDirPath = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".EXCEPTION_DIR_PATH");
    try
    {
      Utility.createFile(exceptionDirPath + "/" + this.fileName, this.ftpData);

      String message = "Error while performing post process :: " + this.fileName + ", File is stored in Exception Directory. ";

      message = message = "::ErrorMessage::" + this.errorStr;

      performSendErrorEmail(message);
      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, ":ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void writeFileToInputDir()
    throws Exception
  {
    String inputDirPath = EnvProperties.getProperty(PROCESS_NAME + "." + this.interfaceId + ".INPUT_DIR_PATH");
    try
    {
      String completeFileName = this.interfaceId + "." + this.fileName;
      Utility.createFile(inputDirPath + "/" + completeFileName, this.ftpData);

      String message = "Interface has saved the file: " + completeFileName + " to input Directory ";

      performSendErrorEmail(message);

      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, ":ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void updateLog()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      this.processLabel = (this.processLabel + ",FilesProcessed=" + this.fileCounter);

      updateProcessLabel(this.processLabel);

      MessageDataOperation.updateMessageSentData(this.processId, "Y");

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.INFO, "Process Completed, Process Label:" + this.processLabel);


      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, ":ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }

  public void updateLog1()
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      this.processLabel += ",FilesProcessed=0";

      updateProcessLabel(this.processLabel);

      MessageDataOperation.updateMessageSentData(this.processId, "Y");

      this.logger.log(PASLevel.INFO, "Process Completed, Process Label:" + this.processLabel);


      return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.logger.log(PASLevel.SYSTEM_ERROR, ":ProcessLabel:" + this.processLabel + ":Error:" + e.getMessage(), new LogParameters(this.processId, PROCESS_NAME, this.processLabel, e));


      throw e;
    }
  }


}
```

This code makes use of a FTP timer even generator to kick off a transaction daily. The problem is, when the timer triggers its spitting out that error and at the same time the transaction is going through. I did try multiple try/catch blocks, but could not get any additional information so far. This has been happening ever since a server outage. Can anyone suggest